# How can I intercept and log errors that occur when hitting the TokenEndpoint?

Tags: spring, logging, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Given the changes in the logging that were done in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1271 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1290, I think it may be hard to please everyone with the logging that is present in the token endpoint. For instance, I would like to catch anything that falls to the simple `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` to be an error statement with a log with a stack trace.

What would be the best way to intercept the exceptions that occur in the error endpoint, so that custom logging could be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How we ended up solving this was using `spring-aop`. We simply intercepted the correct places and log an error message during it:

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class OAuthErrorLoggingAspect {

    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Error during token generation: ";

    @Before("execution("
            + "public * "
            + "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint"
            + ".TokenEndpoint.handleException(Exception)) && args(ex))")
    public void handleExceptionLogging(Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof ClientAbortException) {
            log.debug(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
        } else {
            log.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
        }
    }

    @Before("execution("
            + "public * "
            + "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint"
            + ".TokenEndpoint.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException("
            + "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException)) && args(ex))")
    public void handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedLogging(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        log.debug(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
    }

    @Before("execution("
            + "public * "
            + "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint"
            + ".TokenEndpoint.handleClientRegistrationException("
            + "Exception)) && args(ex))")
    public void handleClientRegistrationErrorLogging(Exception ex) {
        log.debug(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
    }

    @Before("execution("
            + "public * "
            + "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint"
            + ".TokenEndpoint.handleException("
            + "org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception)) && args(ex))")
    public void handleOAuth2ExceptionLogging(OAuth2Exception ex) {
        log.debug(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use override `HandlerExceptionResolverComposite` exception handler defined in `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. This will composites all exception resolvers in into one exception resolver. We can then define your own exception resolvers.

One of the exception resolvers we can use is `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, this will enable AOP based exception handling by involving classes with `@ControllerAdvice` annotation.

In our custom controller advice, we can use handler for different exceptions:

```
@ExceptionHandler({OAuth2Exception.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleOAuth2Exception(final OAuth2Exception exception, final WebRequest request) {
    LOGGER.debug("OAuth failed on request processing", exception);
```